# How can I suppress checkHadoopHome?

Tags: hadoop

I'm writing (and testing) a library which connects to a remote HDFS using `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client`.

Tests work well but I see following log.

```
11:41:36.473 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:3559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:3554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:485)
```

How can I suppress the checking logic or what entry should I put on my `core-site.xml` or `hdfs-site.xml`?

Please note, again, that this is a client library.

Comment: You mean you put your XML files on the classpath instead of in `$HADOOP_HOME/conf`? Why don't you just pass `-Dhadoop.home.dir` option or export the env var?

Comment: @OneCricketeer exactly!

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to set one of those values?

Comment: @OneCricketeer As written, the code resides in a library module which will be imported to applications. I put those `-xml` files in the library and the library code loads those files. Thanks.

Comment: I've actually never seen this error before, so I don't have an answer, but if you set either to any location, do your local files actually get used?